# How to show post title that I am creating in the content editor?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is this possible in `Wordpress`? I am trying to use a pre-defined template for my contents. To do that, I use something like this:

```
add_filter( 'default_content', 'custom_editor_content' );
function custom_editor_content( $content ) {

     $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'=> 15,   
        'orderby'  => array( 
                'ID' => 'DESC' ,
            ),
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $query_contents=Array();

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        array_push($query_contents,Array(
            "id"=>get_the_ID(),
            "title"=>get_the_title(),
            "url"=>get_permalink(),
        ));

    }
    $content = '



    '.get_the_title( $id ).'


    ';
   return $content;
}
```

But I can't get the post title *(the one I am creating at that moment)*, somehow. Does someone know how to do this? If I put the while statement into $content, it shows the whole query in the editor and that's not what I want of course.

**All I want to do is to fetch the post title and show it in the content editor (after posting or before, that wouldn't matter)**

Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I think that at the time of execution of this script (which is before the page loads) the post you are "creating" doesn't exists yet and therefore you cannot fetch its title.

You can try following, as the default_content supports second argument, which is the edited post:

```
add_filter( 'default_content', 'custom_editor_content' );
function custom_editor_content( $content, $post ) {

    ...
    $content = '



    '.$post->post_title.'


    ';
   return $content;
}
```

However I think you will be facing the same issue as mentioned at the beginning of my answer. If you want to add title to content for new post, you will probably need a javascript which will copy the title into content as you write it (only if the content is still empty).

Comment: Nope, not working for me. It just shows empty, no title, nothing at all.